# Turn list into polygon that scales

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have used latex and in particular tikz quite a bit. Using this I was able to create the image shown below.

[image]

The following short code was used to create the image.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\begin{tikzpicture}[background rectangle/.style={fill=black},
                    show background rectangle]

\def\pages{
Home, 
Events,
Pictures,
Video, 
Contact,
About, 
Map
}

\def\ngon{7}

\node[regular polygon,regular polygon sides=\ngon,minimum size=3cm] (p) {};

\foreach\page [count=\x] in \pages{\node[color=white, shift={(\x*360/7+35:0.4)}] (p\x) at (p.corner \x){\page};}

\foreach\i in {1,...,\numexpr\ngon-1\relax}{
  \foreach\j in {\i,...,\x}{
    \draw[thin, orange, dashed] (p\i) -- (p\j);
  }
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I have tried for the last few hours to recreate the same image using 'HTMLæ, 'CSS' and 'Javascript'. I used the 'canvas' element to draw the lines, however I ran into a series of problems as can be seen in the image below

[image]

Which was made with the following code. I tried to the best of my abilities to minimize the code. The code can be found at the bottom of the post. The code has the following problems

- Scalability. The text in the image is not the same as in the 'body' of the page.
- The image hides the rest of the text in the body
- To place the text outside the figure is hardcoded
- The last minor problem is that the first element in the list is not drawn

I would like to address the problems above, but I am unsure how to proceed. Again I am not married to the idea of using canvas (can a better result be done using nodes and elements instead). However, the output should mimic the first image as closely as possible.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Canvas octagon</title>

    <style>
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            color:white;
            background:black;
        }

        canvas {
            display: block;
        }

        html,
        body {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0px;
            border: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            /*  Disable scrollbars */
            display: block;
            /* No floating content on sides */
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="polygon"></canvas>
    <h2>more space</h2>
    <ol id="poly">
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Pictures</li>
        <li>Video</li>
        <li>Events</li>
        <li>Map</li>
        <li>Apply?</li>
        <li>Recepies</li>
    </ol>
some more text here
    <script>
        (function() {
            var canvas = document.getElementById('polygon'),
                context = canvas.getContext('2d');

            // resize the canvas to fill browser window dynamically
            window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas, false);

            function resizeCanvas() {
                canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
                canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

                /**
                 * Your drawings need to be inside this function otherwise they will be reset when 
                 * you resize the browser window and the canvas goes will be cleared.
                 */
                drawStuff();
            }
            resizeCanvas();

            function drawStuff() {
                // do your drawing stuff here

                context.beginPath();
                context.translate(120, 120);
                context.textAlign = "center";

                var edges = document.getElementById("poly").getElementsByTagName("li");
                var sides = edges.length
                var angle = (Math.PI * 2) / sides;
                var radius = 50;

                context.save();
                for (var i = 0, item; item = edges[i]; i++) {
                    console.log("Looping: index ", i, "item " + item.innerText);
                    var start_x = radius * Math.cos(angle * i);
                    var start_y = radius * Math.sin(angle * i);
                    context.lineTo(start_x, start_y);

                    var new_x_text = 1.4 * radius * Math.cos(angle * i);
                    var new_y_text = 1.4 * radius * Math.sin(angle * i);
                    context.fillText(item.innerText, new_x_text, new_y_text);

                    context.strokeStyle = 'orange';
                    for (var j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                        var new_x = radius * Math.cos(angle * j);
                        var new_y = radius * Math.sin(angle * j);
                        context.moveTo(start_x, start_y);
                        context.lineTo(new_x, new_y);
                        console.log(new_x, new_y);
                    }

                    context.fillStyle = 'white'
                }

                var new_x = radius * Math.cos(0);
                var new_y = radius * Math.sin(0);
                context.lineTo(new_x, new_y);
                context.stroke();

            }
        })();
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Using the canvas to render content

First I will say that using javascript will be longer than if you use some symbolic representation language like Latex. It is designed to do graphical representations with the minimum of fuss. The actual code base that makes it work is substantial but hidden for the general user.

#### Using the DOM

As the content for the canvas is stored in the DOM it also a good idea to store as much information as you can in the DOM, the colors, fonts, etc can all be stored in an element`s dataset.

For this I have put the settings in the ordered list. It contains all the settings, but there is also a default set of settings in the rendering function. The elements dataset will overwrite the defaults, or you can not add any dataset properties and let it all use the defaults.

#### Vetting settings

In the example below I have only put a minimum of vetting. People tend to put quotes around everything in the DOM as numbers can sometimes not work if represented as a string, I force all the numbers to the correct type. Though to be safe I should have checked to see if indeed they are valid numbers, the same for the other settings. I have just assumed that they will be correctly formatted.

#### The function

All the work is done in a function, you pass it the query string needed to find the list and canvas. It then uses the list items to render to the canvas.

#### Relative sizes

As the canvas size is not always known (it could be scaled via CSS) you need to have some way to specify size independent of pixels. For this I use a relative size. Thus the font size is as a fraction of the canvas size eg `data-font-size = 16` means that the font will be 1/16th of the canvas height. The same for the line width, and the dash size is a multiple of the line width. eg `data-line-dash = 4` means that the dashes are 4 times the length of the line width.

#### Element's data properties

To use data set you add the property to the element in the HTML prefixed with the word `data-` then the property name/s separated by `"-"`. In javascript you can not use `"-"` directly as part of a variable name (it's a subtract operator) so the property names are converted to camelcase (the same as CSS properties), and stored in the element's `dataset` property.

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div id="divElement" data-my-Value = "some data"></div>

<script>
    // the property of divElement is available as
    console.log(divElement.dataset.myValue); // output >> "some data"
</script>
```

#### Scaling & rendering

The canvas is rendered at a ideal size (512 in this case) but the transform is set to ensure that the render fits the canvas. In this example I scale the x and y axis) the result is that the image does not have a fixed aspect.

#### Background

The canvas is transparent by default, but I do clear it in case you rerender to it. Anything under the canvas should be visible.

I first render the lines, then the text, clearing a space under the text to remove the lines. ctx.clearRect ensure the a canvas rect is transparent.

#### Drawing lines

To draw the lines you have two loops, From each item you draw a line to every other item. You don't want to draw a line more than once, so the inner loop starts at the current outer loops position + 1. This ensures a line is only rendered one.

#### Example

The example shows what I think you are after. I have add plenty of comments, but if you have questions do ask in the comments below.

I assumed you wanted the ordered list visible. If not use a CSS rule to hide it, it will not affect the canvas rendering.

Also if you size the canvas via CSS you may get a mismatch between canvas resolution and display size. This can result in blurred pixels, and also some high res displays will set canvas pixels to large. If this is a problem there are plenty of answers on SO on how to deal with blurred canvas rendering and hi res displays (like retina).

```js
function drawConnected(listQ, canvasQ) {

  const list = document.querySelector(listQ);
  if(list === null){ 
      console.warn("Could not find list '" + listQ +"'");
      return;
  }
  
  const canvas = document.querySelector(canvasQ);
  if(canvas === null){ 
      console.warn("Could not find canvas '" + canvasQ + "'");
      return;
  }

  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  const size = 512; // Generic size. This is scaled to fit the canvas
  const xScale = canvas.width / size;
  const yScale = canvas.height / size;

  // get settings or use dsefault
  const settings = Object.assign({
    fontSize : 16,
    lineWidth : 128,
    lineDash : 4,
    textColor : "White",
    lineColor : "#F90", // orange
    startAngle : -Math.PI / 2,
    font : "arial",
  }, list.dataset);

  // calculate relative sizes. convert deg to randians
  const fontSize = size / Number(settings.fontSize) | 0;  // (| 0 floors the value)
  const lineWidth = size / Number(settings.lineWidth) | 0; 
  const lineDash = lineWidth * Number(settings.lineDash);
  const startAngle = Number(settings.startAngle) * Math.PI / 180; // -90 deg is top of screen
  
  // get text in all the list items
  const items = [...list.querySelectorAll("li")].map(element => element.textContent);
  
  // Set up the canvas 
  // Scale the canvas content to fit.
  ctx.setTransform(xScale,0,0,yScale,0,0);
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,size,size);  // clear as canvas may have content
  ctx.font = fontSize + "px " + settings.font;

  // align text to render from its center
  ctx.textAlign = "center";
  ctx.textBaseline = "middle";

  // set the line details
  ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth;
  ctx.lineCap = "round";
  ctx.setLineDash([lineDash, lineDash]);
  
  // need to make room for text so calculate all the text widths
  const widths = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < items.length; i ++){
      widths[i] = ctx.measureText(items[i]).width;
  }

  // use the max width to find a radius that will fit all text
  const maxWidth = Math.max(...widths);
  const radius = (size/2 - maxWidth * 0.6);
  
  // this function returns the x y position on the circle for item at pos
  const getPos = (pos) => {
      const ang = pos / items.length * Math.PI * 2 + startAngle;
      return [
        Math.cos(ang) * radius + size / 2,
        Math.sin(ang) * radius + size / 2
      ];
  };
  
  // draw lines first
  ctx.strokeStyle = settings.lineColor;
  ctx.beginPath();
  for(let i = 0; i < items.length; i ++){
      const [x,y] = getPos(i);
      for(let j = i+1; j < items.length; j ++){
          const [x1,y1] = getPos(j);
          ctx.moveTo(x,y);
          ctx.lineTo(x1,y1);
      }
  }
  ctx.stroke();

  // draw text        
  ctx.fillStyle = settings.textColor;
  for(let i = 0; i < items.length; i ++){
      const [x,y] = getPos(i);
      ctx.clearRect(x - widths[i] * 0.6, y - fontSize * 0.6, widths[i] * 1.2, fontSize * 1.2);
      ctx.fillText(items[i],x,y);
  }

  // restore default transform;   
  ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
}

// draw the diagram with selector query for ordered list and canvas
drawConnected("#poly","#polygon");
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color:white;
    background:black;
}

canvas {
    display: block;
}

html,
body {
    font-family : arial;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    border: 0;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="polygon" width = "256" height = "256"></canvas>
    <h2>more space</h2>
    <ol id="poly"
      data-font-size = 16
      data-line-width = 128
      data-line-dash = 2
      data-text-color = "white"
      data-line-color = "#F80"
      data-start-angle = "-90"
      data-font = "arial"
    >
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Pictures</li>
        <li>Video</li>
        <li>Events</li>
        <li>Map</li>
        <li>Apply?</li>
        <li>Recepies</li>
    </ol>
```